# How do I make a method private and access it from another class?

Tags: c#, get, scope, set, accessor

I am curious how I can make the addOperands method private rather than public as it is coded now. I have read some examples of get and set accessors and I still don't understand the concept. How would I made the addOperands method private in the CalcEngine class and still be able to use this method from another class?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Project3_WindowsCalculator
{
    class CalcEngine
{
    private int operationResult;

    public int addOperands(int operand1, int operand2) 
    {
        operationResult = operand1 + operand2;
        return operationResult;
    }

    public int subtractOperands(int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        operationResult = operand1 - operand2;
        return operationResult;
    }

    public int multiplyOperands(int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        operationResult = operand1 * operand2;
        return operationResult;
    }

    public int divideOperands(int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        operationResult = operand1 / operand2;
        return operationResult;
    }

}
```

}

And here is the class that uses it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Project3_WindowsCalculator
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window

{
    CalcEngine c = new CalcEngine();
    bool addSelected;
    bool subtractSelected;
    bool multiplySelected;
    bool divideSelected;
    bool operationSelected;
    int operationResult;
    int operand1;
    int operand2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void C_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = "0";
        operationResult = 0;
        addSelected = false;
        subtractSelected = false;
        multiplySelected = false;
        divideSelected = false;
        operationSelected = false;
        operand1 = 0;
        operand2 = 0;
    }

    private void Multiply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (operand1 == 0 && operand2 == 0 && operationSelected == false) //operationSelected makes sure * cannot be pressed more than once at a time
        { //if + is clicked and nothing has been stored into operand1 yet
            Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand1); //store the displayed text into the operand1 variable
        }
        else if (operand1 != 0 && operand2 == 0  && operationSelected == false)
        { //if + is clicked and both operand variables are stored with something
            Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand2); //store what's on the display into the operand 2 variable
            if (addSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.addOperands(operand1, operand2);
                addSelected = false;
            }
            else if (subtractSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.subtractOperands(operand1, operand2);
                subtractSelected = false;
            }
            else if (multiplySelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.multiplyOperands(operand1, operand2);
                multiplySelected = false;
            }
            else if (divideSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.divideOperands(operand1, operand2);
                divideSelected = false;
            }
            txtDisplay.Text = operand1.ToString();
            operand2 = 0; //empty the operand2 variable
        }
        operationSelected = true; multiplySelected = true;
    }

    private void Divide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (operand1 == 0 && operand2 == 0 && operationSelected == false)
        { //if + is clicked and nothing has been stored into operand1 yet
            Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand1); //store the displayed text into the operand1 variable
        }
        else if (operand1 != 0 && operand2 == 0  && operationSelected == false)
        { //if + is clicked and both operand variables are stored with something
            Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand2); //store what's on the display into the operand 2 variable
            if (addSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.addOperands(operand1, operand2);
                addSelected = false;
            }
            else if (subtractSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.subtractOperands(operand1, operand2);
                subtractSelected = false;
            }
            else if (multiplySelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.multiplyOperands(operand1, operand2);
                multiplySelected = false;
            }
            else if (divideSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.divideOperands(operand1, operand2);
                divideSelected = false;
            }
            txtDisplay.Text = operand1.ToString();
            operand2 = 0; //empty the operand2 variable
        }
        operationSelected = true; divideSelected = true;

    }

    private void Subtract_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (operand1 == 0 && operand2 == 0 && operationSelected == false)
        { //if + is clicked and nothing has been stored into operand1 yet
            Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand1); //store the displayed text into the operand1 variable
        }
        else if (operand1 != 0 && operand2 == 0  && operationSelected == false)
        { //if + is clicked and both operand variables are stored with something
            Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand2); //store what's on the display into the operand 2 variable
            if (addSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.addOperands(operand1, operand2);
                addSelected = false;
            }
            else if (subtractSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.subtractOperands(operand1, operand2);
                subtractSelected = false;
            }
            else if (multiplySelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.multiplyOperands(operand1, operand2);
                multiplySelected = false;
            }
            else if (divideSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.divideOperands(operand1, operand2);
                divideSelected = false;
            }
            txtDisplay.Text = operand1.ToString();
            operand2 = 0; //empty the operand2 variable
        }
        operationSelected = true; subtractSelected = true;
    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (operand1 == 0 && operand2 == 0 && operationSelected == false){ //if + is clicked and nothing has been stored into operand1 yet
            Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand1); //store the displayed text into the operand1 variable
        }
        else if (operand1 != 0 && operand2 == 0  && operationSelected == false)
        { //if + is clicked and both operand variables are stored with something
            Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand2); //store what's on the display into the operand 2 variable
            if (addSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.addOperands(operand1, operand2);
                addSelected = false;
            }
            else if (subtractSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.subtractOperands(operand1, operand2);
                subtractSelected = false;
            }
            else if (multiplySelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.multiplyOperands(operand1, operand2);
                multiplySelected = false;
            }
            else if (divideSelected)
            {
                operand1 = c.divideOperands(operand1, operand2);
                divideSelected = false;
            }
            txtDisplay.Text = operand1.ToString();
            operand2 = 0; //empty the operand2 variable
        }
        operationSelected = true; addSelected = true;
    }

    private void Equals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand2);

        if(addSelected){
            operationResult = c.addOperands(operand1, operand2);
            //operand1 = operationResult;
        }

        if(subtractSelected){
            operationResult = c.subtractOperands(operand1, operand2);
        }

        if(multiplySelected){
            operationResult = c.multiplyOperands(operand1, operand2);
        }

        if(divideSelected){
            operationResult = c.divideOperands(operand1, operand2);
        }

        txtDisplay.Text = operationResult.ToString();
        Int32.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out operand1);

        addSelected = false;
        subtractSelected = false;
        multiplySelected = false;
        divideSelected = false;
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void Seven_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "7" : txtDisplay.Text + "7";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void Eight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "8" : txtDisplay.Text + "8";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void Nine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "9" : txtDisplay.Text + "9";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void Four_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "4" : txtDisplay.Text + "4";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void Five_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "5" : txtDisplay.Text + "5";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void Six_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "6" : txtDisplay.Text + "6";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void One_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "1" : txtDisplay.Text + "1";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void Two_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "2" : txtDisplay.Text + "2";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void Three_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text == "0" || operationSelected ? "3" : txtDisplay.Text + "3";
        operationSelected = false;
    }

    private void btn_0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}

    private void Off_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        C_Click(sender, e);
        txtDisplay.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    private void On__Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}

    private void On_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        C_Click(sender, e);
        txtDisplay.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: you can cut most of your code because its redundant here. dont put all your code here.just keep the addOperands and Add_Click.remove other

Comment: Can you explain a little on why you want it private?

Comment: the only way to access private method is to access with public constructor/property/method.

Comment: Private MEANS you can't access it from another class.

Comment: The way you make a private method from a public one is make a design decision

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) about *Access Modifiers*. If want to protect your class from external assemblies simply make it `internal` but if you want something different I have several suggestions. (I'm not sure what you need so I posted all my suggestions now)

**Method 1:** Getter-only property

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Read-only access from outside, no 'set'
    public object RestrictedMember { get; private set; }
}
```

---

**Method 2:** Protected modifier

With this modifier only derived class can access the member.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected object RestrictedMember;
}

public DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {
        // You can access base class's protected member
        RestrictedMember = new object();
    }
}
```

---

**Method 3:** Delegates

For methods you can declare your own delegate.

```
public delegate string MyDelegate(int a, int b);
public class MyClass
{
    // Also you should make it readonly or getter-only property if you don't want outside changes
    public MyDelegate restrictedMethod = _restrictedMethod;

    private string _restrictedMethod(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b).ToString();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void It(MyClass mc)
    {
        // You can call method and get result
        string sumAsStr = mc.restrictedMethod(3, 5);
    }
}
```

*I'm not tested them. Some minor bugs/syntax errors can be fixed.*

Answer (score 0):

If both the classes are in the same assembly, you could make function internal instead of private. Anything internal can be accessed in the same assembly but is not visible to any class outside the assembly.

The getter and setter accessors you might have seem could be referring to making properties of a class immutable outside the class.

Consider a class Foo

Public class Foo
{
   Public string Bar { get; private set; }

.. 
}

In this case, the Bar property can be accessed outside of Foo but it can not be modified outside of Foo.

Answer (score 0):

I just coded up an answer to another question that might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468619/2566963