# What passable value can I use, besides an object instance, to access multiple functions?

Tags: c#, oop, dictionary, architecture

I'm learning C# and I'm looking for a solution for a problem that perhaps is caused by bad architecture and doesn't affect real-life programs.

I want to pass "something" (not necessarily a class) that holds multiple functions and doesn't need to be instantiated, for example, I want to have a class with a list of hours and tasks in a dictionary, so, for example, at 12:00 I want the class to 'lunch', but that lunch may depend on other variables, so I have a dict entry to check like {12, LunchTask}, LunchTask is subclass/implementation/derivation of 'Task' so we can safely pass it and call something like SomeTask.Start, SomeTask.Pause, SomeTask.Stop.

I though about using Dictionary (int,System.Type) but couldn't get it working, I also tried statics but they can't be subclassed and delegates are for single functions as far as I know. I just want to pass something in a dict that has functions that can be accessed directly without instantiating. One solution I know would work but I find very inelegant is to have a static class with instances of all the different tasks.

I don't know of any better way to achieve such a basic functionality and perhaps I'm doing everything terribly wrong. So if you guys could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Here is some (pseudo-c#) code:

```
public abstract class Task {
    public abstract void ExecuteTask ();
    public virtual void PauseTask() {Console.WriteLine ("Task Paused")}
    public virtual void StopTask() {Console.WriteLine ("Task Stopped")}
}

public class Lunch : Task {
    public override void ExecuteTask ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Lunch Task Started");
    }
}

//the following is gonna be instantiated
public class Human {
    Dictionary<int, Something> attributions =  new Dictionary<int, Something>(){{12, Lunch}};
    void ToBeCalledEveryHour () {
        int hour = someHour();
        if (attributions.ContainsKey(hour))
            attributions[hour].ExecuteTask();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be looking for `Action` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) or `Func` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Without you showing any of your code, or clearly describing what you're trying to achieve, it's nearly impossible to tell what you're after. It sounds like you *might* be attempting to create a `Dictionary<int, Task>` or maybe a `Dictionary<int, Func<Task>>`, or one of the other bcl delegate types, but as it stands it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Thank you, I'm going to take a look. PrestonGuillot: I'm sorry, I'm going to edit the question and add some code. The first option would need an instance afaik, I'm not sure about the second one, I'm going to google for it.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: I just added some code, it's not pretty nor working but i hope it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can use either Object pool pattern or Factory Pattern.

In case of Object pool pattern you can have a Map in which key should be the string that will identify the object uniquely, for example it can be class name and the value can be corresponding object.

Like this:

```
public abstract class Task {
public abstract void ExecuteTask ();
public virtual void PauseTask() {Console.WriteLine ("Task Paused")}
public virtual void StopTask() {Console.WriteLine ("Task Stopped")}
}

public class Lunch : Task {
   public override void ExecuteTask ()
   {
     Console.WriteLine ("Lunch Task Started");
   }
}

public class ObjectCollection{
    Dictionary<string,Task> objectStringMapper= new Dictionary<string,string>();
    Dictionary<string,Task> objectTimeMapper= new Dictionary<string,string>();
    public ObjectCollection(){
        objectMapper.Add("Lunch",new LunchTask());
        objectTimeMapper.Add(12,new LunchTask());        
    }
    public Task getObject(string objId){
        return objectMapper.get(objId);
    }
    public Task getObject(int time){
        return objectTimeMapper.get(time);
    } 

 }

public class Human {
    ObjetCollection objectsFactory = new ObjectCollection();
    void ToBeCalledEveryHour () {
        int hour = someHour();
        if (attributions.ContainsKey(hour))
            objectsFactory.getObject(hour).ExecuteTask();
      }
}
```

Or you can Opt for Factory Pattern , in which you can have a class for creating objects using either reflection or switch case.

Note: Since I'm a Java Developer and new to c# you may find some syntax's wrong.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it seems to be the closest solution to what I wanted, so for future reference I think this answer is the most significant, however, I ended up dropping that architecture and going with another approach.

Comment: What was the difficulty? @Alan C.

Comment: I just think that's not a very good approach at all, at least for C#, I'm really loving C# but you can't just type your mind out like Python which is the language I'm most used to. I think your solution was quite good and I'm sure it's going to help others in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple enough thing if the parameters to your methods are always the same.
However, if they're going to be different, this would be *extremely* difficult.

I will say, I don't see much advantage in this vs. just instantiating the object you want outside of your Dispatcher and calling methods on it inside.

But here is a very basic example of what you are trying to achieve (edited in response to the code you posted):

```
//Method Call:
Dictionary<int, System.Type> attributions = new Dictionary<int, System.Type>(){{12, typeof[Lunch]}};
Dispatcher(attributions);

//Dispatcher
public void Dispatcher(IDictionary<int, System.Type> dictionary) {
    int hour = SomeHour()

    // Instantiate object
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(attributions[hour]);

    //Build args
    var args = new object[]{
        new object(),
    };

    // Invoke method
    type.InvokeMember("ExecuteTask", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null, obj, args);
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind, you're trying to apply weak-typing principles to a strongly typed language. Be prepared for an exception to be thrown the instant something doesn't match up.

Comment: Thank you, that seems very complicated for such a basic functionality however. Perhaps the only option to keep things simple is to create a static class and instantiate there all the Task subclasses, so I could pass the instances in the dictionary value and instead of "Something" I would use "Task". That would work I think but I have no idea if it's acceptable.

Comment: I feel your pain. Coming from a Perl background this should just be:
Dispatcher($dictionary)
$dictionary->{SomeHour()}->ExecuteTask();

Comment: Thank you. I ended up dropping that entire code. I've previously used that approach in python with enormous success. It would more clearly represent a to-do list that is associated with persons, but it seems passing logic blocks in c# is not as easy as it's in python. I always try to architect my programs to closely reflect the real-life interactions, and in python I could do that easily, but it seems I'm going to try different approaches in C#. I'm not complaining or saying C# is bad, I'm just going to have to think a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following to store a dictionary of functions where each function has an identical signature.

You could then pass a reference to such a dictionary.  You could also pass a reference to the static Compute method to any method that accepts a Func<ArithmeticFunction, int, int, int>

```
internal enum ArithmeticFunction
{
   Add,
   Subtract,
   Multiply,
   Divide,
   Min,
   Max,
}

internal static class FunctionMap
{
   private static readonly Dictionary<ArithmeticFunction, Func<int, int, int>> s_map;

   static FunctionMap()
   {
      s_map = new Dictionary<ArithmeticFunction, Func<int, int, int>>();

      s_map[ArithmeticFunction.Add] = (x, y) => x + y;
      s_map[ArithmeticFunction.Subtract] = (x, y) => x - y;
      s_map[ArithmeticFunction.Multiply] = (x, y) => x * y;
      s_map[ArithmeticFunction.Divide] = (x, y) => x / y;
      s_map[ArithmeticFunction.Min] = System.Math.Min;
      s_map[ArithmeticFunction.Max] = System.Math.Max;
   }

   //Don't allow callers access to the core map.  Return them a copy instead.
   internal static Dictionary<ArithmeticFunction, Func<int, int, int>> GetCopy()
   {
      return new Dictionary<ArithmeticFunction, Func<int, int, int>>(s_map); 
   }

   internal static int Compute(ArithmeticFunction op, int x, int y)
   {
      return s_map[op](x, y);
   }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Example 1:");
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(FunctionMap.Compute(ArithmeticFunction.Add, 12, 4));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(FunctionMap.Compute(ArithmeticFunction.Subtract, 12, 4));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(FunctionMap.Compute(ArithmeticFunction.Multiply, 12, 4));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(FunctionMap.Compute(ArithmeticFunction.Divide, 12, 4));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(FunctionMap.Compute(ArithmeticFunction.Min, 12, 4));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(FunctionMap.Compute(ArithmeticFunction.Max, 12, 4));

   var safeCopy = FunctionMap.GetCopy();
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Example 2:");
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(safeCopy[ArithmeticFunction.Add](72, 9));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(safeCopy[ArithmeticFunction.Subtract](72, 9));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(safeCopy[ArithmeticFunction.Multiply](72, 9));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(safeCopy[ArithmeticFunction.Divide](72, 9));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(safeCopy[ArithmeticFunction.Min](72, 9));
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(safeCopy[ArithmeticFunction.Max](72, 9));
```

Output is as follows:

```
Example 1:
16
8
48
3
4
12

Example 2:
81
63
648
8
9
72
```